# Solr & Hbase integration using NGDATA Hbase-indexer

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, hbase, integration

Data is not reflected in Solr UI after indexing the Hbase table data using [Hbase indexer.](https://github.com/NGDATA/hbase-indexer) I followed the steps provided in [Hbase-indexer](https://github.com/NGDATA/hbase-indexer).
1. Created Hbase table
2. Copied the hbase-sep jar files to the lib directory of HBase.
3. Created an indexer xml file with the index information 
4. created an indexer using the indexer xml file.

After all the above steps i tried to search using Solr UI i dont see the data being reflected there. Has anyone worked on this?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to verify:
1. Does Hbase having replication_scope = 1.
2. Are you using put to load the data? Because, indexer will pick wal's(write ahead logs). And put will create wal, where as bulk load will not.
3. Verify the indexer mapping details of hbase column qualifiers to the solr fields.

Comment: Thanks for responding @ramzy.

Comment: 1. I have set the below value for replication in hbase-site.xml <property>
    <name>replication.source.ratio</name>
    <value>1.0</value>
  </property>                                        2. Put command used for loading data.         3. Used the same indexer provided in the hbase indexer wiki site.                               Still couldn't figure out the issue. Can you please guide me on this am new to hbase and solr.

Comment: The replication scope should be set for that table. Try this                                                                         alter ‘table’, {NAME => ‘column-family’, REPLICATION_SCOPE => 1}

Comment: I tried but still no data seen in solr UI. 
`output in UI
    {
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*:*",
      "_": "1445252173809",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  }
}`

Comment: When i list the indexers i see that there are 0 running processes.What could be the issue here?
`demo01
  + Lifecycle state: ACTIVE
  + Incremental indexing state: SUBSCRIBE_AND_CONSUME
  + Batch indexing state: INACTIVE
  + SEP subscription ID: Indexer_demo01
  + SEP subscription timestamp: 2015-10-19T19:43:11.666+08:00
  + Connection type: solr
  + Connection params:
    + solr.collection = collection1
  + Indexer config:  215 bytes, use -dump to see content
  + Batch index config: (none)
  + Default batch index config: (none)
  + Processes
    + 0 running processes
    + 0 failed processes`

Comment: Try to drop the indexers and add them again. Please verify if the zoo keeper and Hbase master are running properly.

Comment: After deleting and adding an indexer getting the below error. 
`Error: ERROR supervisor.IndexerSupervisor: Problem starting indexer demo01
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat`
I have the required jar lucene-core-3.3.0.jar

Comment: PostingsFormat is not there in lucene-core-3.3.0 jar. I see that its there atleast in 4.2.1 version. So use that jar and try. Also if you use maven, I assume you might not get this issue.